# Error running egrep on Solaris

Tags: grep, solaris

Sun OS 5.8
Bash shell script
Oracle 10g database

```
    Error  1  the command executing at the time of the error was  egrep ORA-\|TNS-\|PLS-\|Error\|PLW-\|IMP-\|EXP-\|RMAN-\|SQL- alert_work.log > alert.err  on line  11
```

The "egrep" line runs successfully when I run it manually. But in a bash script (cron job) it gets the above error. Here is the script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    SID=$ORACLE_SID
    DOMAIN=$(uname -n)
    DBALIST='dbak@xxx.com'
    YESTERDAY=`TZ=CST+24 date +%Y-%m-%d`

    cd $ORACLE_HOME/admin/$SID/bdump
    mv alert_${SID}.log alert_work.log
    touch alert_${SID}.log
    cat alert_work.log >> alert_${SID}.hist
    egrep ORA-\|TNS-\|PLS-\|Error\|PLW-\|IMP-\|EXP-\|RMAN-\|SQL-  alert_work.log > alert.err

    if [ `cat alert.err|wc -l` -gt 0 ]
    then
          mailx -s "${DOMAIN}.${SID} ALERT LOG ERRORS FOUND" $DBALIST < alert.err.log
    fi

    /usr/bin/mv alert_work.log $ORACLE_HOME/admin/$SID/bdump/hist/alert_${SID}_${YESTERDAY}.log
    exit
```

Comment: Run `which egrep` in your shell and make sure you are using the same one in your crontab.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspicious of your egrep regular expression, The fact that you have not quoted it, and create a script from within a Bash script leads and then run the script, leads me to think that you will end up with:
egrep ORA-|TNS-|PLS-|Error|PLW-|IMP-|EXP-|RMAN-|SQL-  alert_work.log > alert.err
which is not what you intended. Try:
egrep 'ORA-\|TNS-\|PLS-\|Error\|PLW-\|IMP-\|EXP-\|RMAN-\|SQL-'  alert_work.log > alert.err
That *should* preserve the back slashes.